# glReadPixels for entire windows (OpenGL)

Tags: c, opengl

I wanna save all RGB values of window on OpenGL.
And want to check values as 'int' (because i have to use it )
I tried to save it by each pixels using for loop, and it works. 
However If I tried to glReadpixels onece, it fails to check. what's problem?

This code works. (saves pixel RGB correctly, and I can check it using cout)

```
int width = 50;
int height = 50;
for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
    {
        unsigned char pick_col[3];
        glReadPixels(j , i , 1 , 1 , GL_RGB , GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE , pick_col);
        cout << (int)pick_col[0] << " " << (int)pick_col[1] << " " << (int)pick_col[2] << endl;
    }
}
```

But this code does not work. (there is strange values in pixel array. several values are correct)

```
GLubyte pixelarray[width*height*3]; 
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelarray);

for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
    {
        cout << (int)pixelarray[i*width*3 + j*3] << " " (int)pixelarray[i*width*3 + j*3 +1] << " " << (int)pixelarray[i*width*3 + j*3+2] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: make sure the [`GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) is set correctly

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem. It should be GL_RGBA and 4channel array

```
GLubyte pixelarray[width*height*4]; 
glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelarray);

for(int i=0; i<height; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<width; j++)
    {
        cout << (int)pixelarray[i*width*4 + j*4] << " "     (int)pixelarray[i*width*4 + j*4 +1] << " " << (int)pixelarray[i*width*4 + j*4+2]     << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Well. Using RGB would also work, given you would set the correct pack alignment...